# Pasar un ArrayList como parametro en un metodo

Tags: java

supongamos que tengo un ArrayList con elementos tipo String y deseo crear una función que me reciba como parametros un ArrayList y un String y me conpruebe si el elemento se encuentra o no, mi idea fue algo del tipo

```
public boolean Esta (ArrayList<> lista,String palabra1){
  for(String palabra: lista){
    if(palabra.equals(palabra1){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false; 
}
```

entiendo que estoy cometiendo un error al ingresarlo como parametro un ArrayList, me gustaria saber si hay forma de crear una funcion de este estilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasale un ArrayList de tipo String en el parámetro de la función.
Te muestro un ejemplo de código que funciona:

```
public class Stack {

    public static boolean esta(ArrayList<String> list,String palabra1) {
    for(String palabra: list){
        if (palabra.equals(palabra1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

        a.add("Steve");
        a.add("Daniel");
        a.add("John");
        a.add("Maxi");
        a.add("Jeni");

        System.out.println(esta(a, "Steve")); 
    }
}
```